# update_many objects by reference to objects in same documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Let's say I have a collection like the following.  For every document that contains `animals.horse`, I want to set `animals.goat` equal to `animals.horse` (so the horses don't get lonely or outnumbered).

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "animals": {
      "goat": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "animals": {
      "cow": 1,
      "horse": 2,
      "goat": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "animals": {
      "horse": 5
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "animals": {
      "cow": 1
    }
  }
]
```

In Mongo shell, this works as desired:

```
db.collection.update(
   {"animals.horse": { "$gt": 0 }},
   [ { "$set": { "animals.goat": "$animals.horse" } } ],
   { "multi": true }
)
```

which achieves the desired result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "animals": {
      "goat": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "animals": {
      "cow": 1,
      "goat": 2,
      "horse": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "animals": {
      "goat": 5,
      "horse": 5
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "animals": {
      "cow": 1
    }
  }
]
```

However, this doesn't work in pymongo -- the collection is unaltered.

```
db.collection.update_many( filter = {'animals.horse': {'$gt':0} },  
                           update = [ {'$set': {'animals.goat': '$animals.horse' } } ],
                           upsert = True
                        )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There a extra colon in the pymongo example? your filter has {'horse': {'$gt'  :  :  0}}. Shouldn't it be {'$gt' : 0}?

Comment: Thanks @CrunchyLentils that was just a typo in my example, but not my actual code.

Comment: Try setting [slowms](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/#std-label-set-profiling-level-options-slowms) to 0 in the mongod.  That will make it log all queries, so you can inspect exactly what operation that code sent to the database.